# Perfect WebRTC Handshake

Tags: angular, typescript, webrtc, webrtc-android

I have been trying to implement a "perfect" WebRTC handshake.
For this i have implemented the following solution:

https://blog.mozilla.org/webrtc/perfect-negotiation-in-webrtc/

But it seems like that is already no longer working.
Could someone give me a hint on how to create such a handshake?

Most important feature would be to support Chrome and Firefox and to allow adding media after the connection has been established.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Multiple actually, sometimes it is about setting offers when the connection is in the wrong state, sometimes it´s about invalid ufrags. That´s why I would like to look at a "perfect" implementation

Comment: I seem to be having very similar issues. I didn't want to hijack your question with mine though so I've made another one here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956693/webrtc-perfect-negotiation-issues
Did you find a solution to those issues?